# Интересоваться мнением по разным темам / на разные темы

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать?
Интересуйтесь мнением ребёнка по разным темам / на разные темы.
Какой предлог нужно использовать?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написала:"Интересуйтесь **мнением ребенка по разным** **вопросам** (проблемам)" или "Интересуйтесь мнением ребёнка по поводу разных проблем, событий"

На разные темы можно беседовать, писать статьи, в том числе и статьи-мнения, рассуждать; по разным темам можно "пробежаться", а вот мнение как позиция всё-таки *о чём? по каким вопросам? или  по поводу чего?*